# python : cannot instantiate more than one or two variables (SyntaxError raised)

Tags: python, variables, vim, syntax-error

Since yesterday, I'm having a strange issue when testing new Python scripts. When running the script, I get a 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' on one of the first variable assignment.

For exemple, this simple code I made for loading screen options from a text file (that exists in the same directory) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('config.txt')
fullscreen = bool(config.get('Screen', 'fullscreen')
width = int(config.get('Screen', 'width')
height = int(config.get('Screen', 'height')
...
```

When run in the terminal, returns :

```
File "./config.py", line 8
width = int(config.get('Screen', 'width')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

More strangely, when I comment the fullscreen line out, I get the same error... but on the next line (height = ...). Meaning the last one was indeed syntax valid?
Also the problem only occurs on the new files, older ones work perfectly (well, at least there's no error :) ).
And, last but not least... when I'm using another text editor (like kate, I usually use vim), writing the exact same code raises no error either

I tried to reinstall vim as I thought that was where the problem came from, but it's still the same.

Thanks for your time and sorry for my english,
Charles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a trailing right bracket to close `bool`:

```
fullscreen = bool(config.get('Screen', 'fullscreen'))
                                                    ^
```

And the same with `int`:

```
width = int(config.get('Screen', 'width'))
                                         ^
height = int(config.get('Screen', 'height'))
                                           ^
```

Comment: Arf, I looked so far, but the problem was right under my nose.
Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: @Klowx Having an IDE that matches brackets for you definitely helps!

Comment: I have, and don't usually do that kind of mistake. Strangely I didn't made it using kate (which doesn't have a very clear matching bracket IDE, I found)